# Show site content based on user role

Tags: php, users

I am trying to hide cart menu icon if the logged in user is not a subscriber. Right now I have the following code in my `functions.php`, but I still can see the cart if I am a subscriber.

```
  add_filter( 'wpmenucart_menu_item_wrapper', 'wpmenucart_hide_for_visitors', 10, 1 );
function wpmenucart_hide_for_visitors( $menu_item_li ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() || !current_user_can( $current_user, "subscriber" )) {
        return $menu_item_li;
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

I can't see what's wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have errors in the code

First, you are using `current_user_can()` function the wrong way. It has two parameters — `$capability` and `$object_id`. You don't need the latter one, so, in your case:

```
current_user_can('subscriber')
```

In my opinion, it's better to use `capability` instead of `user role` in this function. For example, subscribers can't edit posts, unlike other user roles, so I'd change `'subscriber'` to `'edit_posts'`:

Second, the `if` condition. Your code says that *user must be logged in OR his role `must not be` a subscriber*. It should sound like *the user must be logged in AND `must be not a` subscriber*.

```
add_filter( 'wpmenucart_menu_item_wrapper', 'wpmenucart_hide_for_visitors', 10, 1 );

function wpmenucart_hide_for_visitors( $menu_item_li )
{
    // user is logged in AND his role is higher than a subscriber
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && current_user_can('edit_posts') ) {
        return $menu_item_li;
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

See [current_user_can](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) in the Codex.

Comment: Hi, thanx for your reply. I tried your suggestion, but still no go. It's weird, because I do manage to hide it for non-logged users with my code. It's just that user roles (or capabilities)  are problem. Any other suggestions maybe?

Comment: Do you use a caching plugin? If so, purge the plugin cache and browser cache too.

Comment: I don't use any cache plugin. The fact is - when I remove the code related to user, it is hidden. The second I add the user related code, it is shown. Weird.

Comment: Oh, my fault. I've left a piece of your code unedited. You need `AND` (`&&`) instead of `OR` (`||`) and no need in `!` negation. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Oh, that's right! I can't believe I didn't notice what was wrong with it. Thank you very much for your help!